# Getting the field of form angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a form with some fields.
I'm validating the fields with css classes:(if the field is invalid and the user touched it, then input's border-color = red.)

```
select.ng-invalid.ng-touched,
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched,textarea.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
    border-color: red;
}
```

If the user submits the form without filling one or more field, there would be a danger alert.

**HTML:**

```
  <div ng-show="formInvalid>
       error!
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
 if ($scope.pniyaForm.$valid) {
    $scope.formInvalid = false;
      .....
 } else {
    $scope.formInvalid = true;
 }
```

But, If the user submits the form and has not touched any of the field,  the css classes don't influence.(because user didn't touch...)
I want to add the class in the code.
Does anyone have an idea for an elegant way to do this without writing it on each field separately?

Answer (score 1):

Using ng-class validation in angularjs

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" required ng-model="name" name="name" ng-class="{'has-error': myForm.name.$invalid}" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" required ng-model="age" name="age" ng-class="{'has-error': myForm.age.$invalid}" />
</div>
```

Comment: It does not work for me, do I need to add something else / pay attention to some important detail?

Answer (score 1):

**A possible solution:**

when you are executing your form function, add the following line into it.

```
$scope.$apply(function () {});
```

this line will cause the ng $scope.$watch() run and apply changes if they exist.
may work, may not work, read the following link for deeper understanding of the issue.

http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Answer (score 0):

> If the user submits the form and has not touched any of the field, the css classes don't influence

You need to provide an initial defined value to an ngModel and at least provide the `required` attribute to an input.

Use ngClass to conditionally apply css classes in case some form parts are invalid

```
<form name="myform">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': myform.myinput.$invalid}">
        <input name="myinput" ng-model="myName" class="...." required> 
    </div>
....
</form>

....
// in controller
$scope.myName = "cats"; // form is valid
$scope.myName = "";     // form is invalid, and the css class 'has-error' will be applied
```

Then use ngDisables in your submit button to prevent submission in case the form is invalid

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="myform.$invalid">submit</button>
```